# Error después de instalar Emmet en atom "Fetching local packages failed.Hide output…"

Tags: atom-editor

Cuando termine de instalar el plugin de emmet en atom, al volver abrir me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Fetching outdated packages and themes failed.Hide output…
module.js:597
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
             ^

Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

\\?\C:\ProgramData\cu\atom\app-1.20.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\git-utils\build\Release\git.node
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\cu\atom\app-1.20.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\git-utils\lib\git.js:8:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\cu\atom\app-1.20.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\git-utils\lib\git.js:371:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

y debido a este error no puedo instalar ningún otro plugin.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Windows 10 Home de 64 bits.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. capaz se instalo mal?

Comment: Atom esta actualizado? Talvez te sriva  https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13804